# SUM COLUMN RESULTS 0 GROUP BY IN SUBQUERIES mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
select cs.prod_id, 
    cs.product,
    cs.barcode, 
    COALESCE(total,0) as TOTALQTY, 
    COALESCE(sold,0) as SOLD, 
    COALESCE(total-sold,0) as RMNG  
from product cs left join 
( select sum(totalquantity) as total,stock_id, prod_id 
    from stock 
    group by prod_id 
) xx 
on xx.prod_id = cs.prod_id 
left join 
   ( select sum(quantity)as sold, stock_id 
    from order_list 
    group by barcode
 ) yy 
 on yy.stock_id = xx.stock_id 
 inner join (
    select category, cat_id 
     from category
) cc 
on cc.cat_id=cs.cat_id 
ORDER BY cs.product ASC
```

I tried in single query and it works sold was correct which is 48.
select barcode,sum(quantity)as SOLD, stock_id from order_list group by barcode

| barcode | sold | stock_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30055 | 48 | 457 |

Please help me guys. Thank you

PRODUCT TABLE

| prod_id | product | barcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 58 | BOX-L | 30055 |

STOCK TABLE TOTAL QUANTITY OF THE ITEM IS 70

| stock_id | prod_id | totalquantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 57 | 58 | 20 |
| 457 | 58 | 50 |

ORDERLIST TABLE TOTAL SOLD QUANTITY IS 48

| ol_id | stock_id | barcode | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3822 | 57 | 30055 | 20 |
| 3922 | 457 | 30055 | 4 |
| 3922 | 457 | 30055 | 4 |
| 3922 | 457 | 30055 | 20 |

|

MY OUTPUT
The result is like this. The totalQuantity is Correct but the sold and rmng is incorrect it returns 0 but it has values in a single query.

| prod_id | product | barcode | TotalQuantity | SOLD | RMNG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | BOX-L | 30055 | 70 | 0 | 0 |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

| prod_id | product | barcode | TotalQuantity | SOLD | RMNG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | BOX-L | 30055 | 70 | 48 | 22 |

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` are depending on MySQL' s lenient and indeterminate behavior.  To get a reliable `sold` sum(), you must group by `stock_id` because that is what is in your select list. But you have grouped by `barcode` - unless `stock_id` and `barcode` are 1:1, you will not get a correct result for the SUM().

Comment: If you post a sample of rows from each of the 3 tables together with the expected output, someone should be able to help

Comment: 95% of the time , `Inner join (select... with no aggregation)` can be written more efficiently as a simple join

Comment: Hello Michael I already updated my questions that comes with then tables and its value. Thank you! I hope you can help me.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, could please specify. Thank you